# how to utilize @input and contentEditable with JSX syntax in Vuejs to turn a dom into inputable dom?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jsx, contenteditable

I found a codepen that demonstrates it's possible to combine `@input` with `contentEditable` to create custom input dom, without it has to be an input element. However, I wasn't able to add `@input` with JSX in VueJS. Is it not possible using jsx?

Here is the demo without using JSX, `@input` works in regular dom:
https://codepen.io/supraniti/pen/Lypobx?editors=0010

Thanks

JS

```
Vue.component('editable',{
  template:'<div contenteditable="true" @input="update"></div>',
  props:['content'],
  mounted:function(){
    this.$el.innerText = this.content;
  },
  methods:{
    update:function(event){
      this.$emit('update',event.target.innerText);
    }
  }
})

var example = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    text:"This text is editable!"
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="example">
  <editable :content="text" @update="text = $event"></editable>
  <div>
    <pre>{{$data |json }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ahhhhhh nvm. I found in JSX, you can actually use `onInput` on regular `span`!

Hope it saves someone's time!